# LinqKit nested invoke "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Invoke'"

Tags: c#, .net, linq, npgsql, linqkit

I do not fully understand why nested invokes in select do not work within LinqKit and was wondering if someone would be able to help me understand.

My problem:

First let me line out what works.

So lets say we have three db objects:

```
public class Customer {
     public int Id {get; set;}
     public string Name {get; set;}
     public ICollection<Address> Addresses {get;set;}
}

public class Address {
     public int Id {get;set;}
     public string AddressLine {get;set;}
     public int? Customer_Id { get; set; }
     [ForeignKey("Customer_Id")]
     public virtual Customer Customer {get; set;}
     public int? Coordinates_Id { get; set; }
     [ForeignKey("Coordinates_Id")]
     public virtual Coordinates Coordinates {get; set;}
}

public class Coordinates {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public double Latitude {get;set;}
    public double Longitude {get;set;}
}
```

And I have three models

```
public class CustomerModel {
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public AddressModel Address {get;set;}
}

public class AddressModel{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string AddressLine {get;set;}
  public CoordinatesModel Coordinates {get;set;}
}

public class CoordinatesModel {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public double Latitude {get;set;}
    public double Longitude {get;set;}
}
```

So, now I want to create reusable select expressions. So I create these

```
public static Expression<Func<Address, AddressModel>> ToAddressModel = address =>
     new AddressModel {
       Id = address.Id,
       AddressLine = address.AddressLine,
       Coordinates = new Coordinates {
           Id = address.Coordinates.Id,
           Latitude = address.Coordinates.Latitude,
           Longitude = address.Coordinates.Longitude
       }
     };

public static Expression<Func<Customer, CustomerModel>> ToCustomerModel = customer =>
     new CustomerModel {
       Id = customer.Id,
       Name = customer.Name
       Address = customer.Addresses.AsQueryable().Select(ToAddressModel).ToList()
     };
```

And finally if I go to query this I would write

```
 dbContext.Customers
    .AsExpandable()
    .Select(ToCustomerModel)
    .ToList();
```

This works as expected. But I would like to now make CoordinatesModel more reusable and make an Expression to map it and invoke it in AddressModels Expression.

```
  public static Expression<Func<Coordinates, CoordinatesModel>> ToCoordinates = coordinates =>
      new Coordinates {
           Id = coordinates.Id,
           Latitude = coordinates.Latitude,
           Longitude = coordinates.Longitude
       }

  public static Expression<Func<Address, AddressModel>> ToAddressModel = address =>
     new AddressModel {
       Id = address.Id,
       AddressLine = address.AddressLine,
       Coordinates = ToCoordinatesModel.Invoke(address.Coordinates)
     };
```

Now if I query

```
  dbContext.Customers
    .AsExpandable()
    .Select(ToCustomerModel)
    .ToList();
```

It throws

```
  System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'CoordinatesModel Invoke[Coordinates,Model](System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[Coordinates,CoordinatesModel]], Coordinates)' method
```

This is fine if this is incorrect, I was just trying to understand *why* this is incorrect. If I don't invoke against a collection (like indefinite navigation properties) its fine with nested invokes.

Comment: If anyone looks at this, I should add that the provider is Npgsql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to expressly tell linq that you are expanding the sub expressions - just like when you utilize `.AsExpandable()` on the table - when invoking in a sub set you must expand the parent to traverse the tree and expand the sub expressions.

So.... all you need is to add an `Expand` to the parent expression, in this case

```
public static Expression<Func<Customer, CustomerModel>> ToCustomerModel = customer =>
     new CustomerModel {
       Id = customer.Id,
       Name = customer.Name
       Address = customer.Addresses.AsQueryable().Select(ToAddressModel.Expand()).ToList()
     };
```

The navigation properties are fine, because when you expand the parent of that it will pull in all the sub expressions in order to expand the expression - but the selects (I can only assume are another projection) don't go unless explicitly stated.

Here is the documentation: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx